# Fix "folded" polylines using FME

Tags: overlapping-features, fme-transformer, duplicates

I have a dataset with polylines. For some reason the polylines are drawn back and forth multiple times. You can regard the lines as folded. The number of lines the runs back and forth varies from line to line.

I would like to extract the part of the polyline that runs from the startpoint to the folding point, and remove the rest of the lines. We do not know how many vertices there are from the start point to the folding point.

How would you do this in FME?

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to include a graphic to explain your situation.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that all the lines coexist in pairs with reversed coordinates

[image]

## Method 1:

Make sure you expose the fme_feature_type from the Format Attributes list:

[image]

This method may or may not work, you can use the DuplicateFilter (previously called DuplicateRemover) and use fme_feature_type as attribute. This is the easy way. Otherwise you may have to convert the lines to points remove the duplicates and rebuild the lines.

[image]

## Method 2:

Use the TopologyBuilder transformer. If you test it out you will see the following results (Edge output port)

[image]

In the table there are 2 attributes, one is the _from_node and the second is _to_node

[image]

There are basically the same vertices but one starts and the other ends. The trick was to use a tester and set the following criteria:

_from_node > _to_node

[image]

As you can see, the lines have been separated

[image]